# Aligning two sets of equations with alignat?

Tags: spacing, align, amsmath

I'm having difficulties typing the following: [image]

What I am getting with the code

```
\begin{alignat*}{4}
        f(x)&=x^{-1}, &&\qquad&& f(2) &&= 2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2},\\
        f'(x)&=-x^{-2}, &&\qquad &&f'(2) &&=-\frac{1}{2^{2}},\\
        f''(x)&=2!x^{-3}, &&\qquad &&\frac{f''(2)}{2!}&&=2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^{3}},\\
        f'''(x)&=-3!x^{-4}, &&\qquad &&\frac{f'''(2)}{3!}&&=-\frac{1}{2^{4}},\\
        &\vdotswithin{=}&&\qquad  &&\vdotswithin{=}&&\\
        f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^{n}n!x^{-(n+1)}, &&\qquad&&  \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}&&=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}}.
    \end{alignat*}
```

is something like this: [image]

I have tried very hard but cannot get the spacing right. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why `alignat`? A simple `align` does it: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
        f(x)&=x^{-1}, & f(2) &= 2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2},\\
        f'(x)&=-x^{-2},  &f'(2) &=-\frac{1}{2^{2}},\\
        f''(x)&=2!x^{-3},  &\frac{f''(2)}{2!}&=2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^{3}},\\
        f'''(x)&=-3!x^{-4},  &\frac{f'''(2)}{3!}&=-\frac{1}{2^{4}},\\
        &\vdotswithin{=} & &\vdotswithin{=}\\
        f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^{n}n!x^{-(n+1)}, &  \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}&=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align}
\end{document}`

Comment: You're using too many `&`'s

Comment: Instead of `&&\qquad&& f(2) &&` use `&\qquad&& f(2) &`. Each `&` provides an alternating  `r` and `l` alignment point.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks so much, I was led to believe this wasn't possible to do with align. Please leave your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here we go. A simple `align` (of course with the appropriately set `&`) yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
        f(x)&=x^{-1}, & f(2) &= 2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2},\\
        f'(x)&=-x^{-2},  &f'(2) &=-\frac{1}{2^{2}},\\
        f''(x)&=2!x^{-3},  &\frac{f''(2)}{2!}&=2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^{3}},\\
        f'''(x)&=-3!x^{-4},  &\frac{f'''(2)}{3!}&=-\frac{1}{2^{4}},\\
        &\vdotswithin{=} & &\vdotswithin{=}\\
        f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^{n}n!x^{-(n+1)}, &  \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}&=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have too many `&`'s. Just three per row suffice.

On the other hand, aligning at the `=` signs doesn't seem the best idea, as it creates irregular shapes and the `=` signs are not really related to one another, so I propose a different solution.

I also added `\,` after the `!` when the factorial is immediately followed by another term.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x)&=x^{-1},         \qquad & f(2) &= 2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2},
\\
f'(x)&=-x^{-2},       \qquad & f'(2) &=-\frac{1}{2^{2}},
\\
f''(x)&=2!\,x^{-3},   \qquad & \frac{f''(2)}{2!}&=2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^{3}},
\\
f'''(x)&=-3!\,x^{-4}, \qquad & \frac{f'''(2)}{3!}&=-\frac{1}{2^{4}},
\\
&\vdotswithin{=}      \qquad & & \vdotswithin{=}
\\
f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^{n}n!\,x^{-(n+1)}, \qquad &  \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}&=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& f(x)=x^{-1},          && f(2) = 2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2},
\\[1ex]
& f'(x)=-x^{-2},        && f'(2) =-\frac{1}{2^{2}},
\\[1ex]
& f''(x)=2!\,x^{-3},    && \frac{f''(2)}{2!}=2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^{3}},
\\[1ex]
& f'''(x)=-3!\,x^{-4},  && \frac{f'''(2)}{3!}=-\frac{1}{2^{4}},
\\
&\qquad\vdots           && \qquad\vdots
\\
& f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n}n!\,x^{-(n+1)},\qquad  &&  \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice. And the vertical dot placement according to your suggesting is perfectly fine also. Putting \, after ! also makes things less cluttered. I hope your know that your help is very much appreciated.